# How to sent multipart file request using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, multipartform-data

I can see variations on this question get asked a lot, but after trying many of the suggestions here I still can't get this to quite work. Basically, I have an HTML form that on submit makes a POST multipartfile request to the server:

```
<form class="resource-checkout-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
        id="resourcefilecheckoutform" action="/uploadAndCheckout">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="selectyamlfile" class="filestyle"/>
</form>
```

When the value is changed (a file is selected), I have the form submit automatically:

```
$('#selectyamlfile').change(function() {
      $('#resourcefilecheckoutform').submit();
    });
```

To a REST interface on the server:

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = HttpMessageInformationReturnDataBean.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found")}) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAndCheckout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
```

So far so good, that works, and it uploads the selected file. The problem comes when I try and bypass the form submit redirect by using Ajax to do the request itself. I changed the HTML (removing the action):

```
<form class="resource-checkout-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
        id="resourcefilecheckoutform">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="selectyamlfile" class="filestyle"/>
</form>
```

And moved the action itself to a jquery that occurs when the form is submitted:

```
$('#resourcefilecheckoutform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/uploadAndCheckout',
        type:'POST',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data:$('#resourcefilecheckoutform').serialize(),
        success:function(){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
});
```

It makes the request, but on the server side it complains that the request is not a multipart request:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
```

The number one suggestion I've found is to change the contentType to false, but I'd already done that and it didn't work. So, having searched around I tried a few things, starting with changing the contentType to multipart:

```
$('#resourcefilecheckoutform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/uploadAndCheckout',
        type:'POST',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data:$('#resourcefilecheckoutform').serialize(),
        success:function(){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
});
```

But that caused an error about a missing boundary:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

So I figured I'd add the boundary in, as suggested in some of the other threads:

```
$('#resourcefilecheckoutform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var boundary = '--'+Math.random().toString().substr(2);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/uploadAndCheckout',
        type:'POST',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: $('#resourcefilecheckoutform').serialize(),
        success:function(){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
});
```

But that causes a 400 - Bad Request error with no other real feedback to indicate what it didn't like. I feel like I'm dancing around some fundamental mistake that I'm just not seeing, maybe I'm grabbing the data itself wrong? Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: @zero298 I also think the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part is this ...

```
data: new FormData($('#resourcefilecheckoutform')[0]),
```

Comment: Perfect - I had a feeling I was overthinking this, and that I may have been grabbing the data wrong. Thanks so much!